# Magento 2: What is the best way to observe cart change to modify cart item in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, quote, plugin

I'm using Magento v2.3.4 and i want to modify the cart item, if there is an update on the cart (add to cart, update cart item, and remove cart item). Currently I'm using plugin for quote `collectTotals()` function.

**Is this the correct way to do it, or is there any other method that i can use ?**

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_Quote" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote.php**

```
public function beforeCollectTotals(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject)
{
    $quote = $this->getQuote();
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
       $price = $this->getCustomPrice($item->getProductId());
       if($price){
          $item->setCustomPrice($price);
          $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
       }  
    }
    return [];
}
```

the problem with this plugin is, i got this error after i placed an order:

> Please check the billing address information. "firstname" is required.
> Enter and try again. "lastname" is required. Enter and try again.
> "street" is required. Enter and try again. "city" is required. Enter
> and try again. "telephone" is required. Enter and try again.
> "postcode" is required. Enter and try again. "countryId" is required.
> Enter and try again.

i check the quote address in the database and those field column is empty

Comment: You should use checkout_cart_save_before or checkout_cart_save_after event observer which calls every time when cart modified.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know

1: If you need to override a single method first priority will be **plugin** and in plugin the  first will be **before** plugin and then **after** and if both are not possible then use **around**

2: If plugin is not working then we can **override whole class** but this is the least thing if other solution are not working

while **overriding whole class** if possible override the **only method** that you want to override and if not possible with the specific method that you want then override the whole class with all methods

Comment: kindly explain in the comment why you downvote my answer?

Answer (score 0):

have you used the below two events observer ?

`checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_product_update_after` from this events you can from this observer you can get the `$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();` and then you can use below code to add your custom price you can use the same observer file for both events

```php
$item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
$orignalprice = $product->getFinalPrice();
$customPrice = 10; // your price
$price = $orignalprice + $customPrice;
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Dolphin\Hello\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

have to create CustomPrice.php file that override your price in the Observer Folder.
<?php

```
        namespace Dolphin\Hello\Observer;
     
        use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
     
        class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
        {
            public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
                $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
                $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
                $price = 100; //set your price here
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }
     
        }
```